# How do i select a specific sibling class under a parent class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, scss-mixins

I have two parents classes that have the same name but one has additional child class. I want to only select a child class from the parent class with that additional child class.

```
class = money-styling
     class = compare-at-price
     class = money

class = money-styling
      class = money
```

I want to select money class that has a sibling compare-at-price. Only code I could write was"

```
.money-styling .money{
    color:#ff0000;
}
```

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: For example: `.money-styling .compare-at-price + .money`

Comment: Could you show us some HTML because it's going to depend on the positions in relation to each other - and I'm not sure what a 'child class' is.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this one 

.money-styling .compare-at-price ~ .money{
   color:red;
}
```